# How to access a tag deep inside other tags using xpath from an xml?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have deep nested xml tag Movie which I want to access directly using `xpath`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<collection>
    <genre category="Action">
        <decade years="1980s">
            <movie favorite="True" title="Indiana Jones: The raiders of the lost Ark">
                <format multiple="No">DVD</format>
                <year>1981</year>
                <rating>PG</rating>
                <description>
                'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
                is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
                Covenant before the Nazis.'
                </description>
            </movie>
</decade>
</genre>
</collection>
</xml>
```

How do I access the `movie` tag and its attributes ?
I tried using

```
root  = etee.tostring(above_xml)
print root.xpath("movie")
[]
```

but I get nothing.

Comment: I have not used xpath in python, but your xpath would be either `/collection/genre/decade/movie` or `//movie`. Have you tried them?

Comment: yes and that didnt worked

Comment: Not sure why you'd use `tostring()`; that should be fromstring() if `above_xml` is a string. Then the xpath `//movie` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but try this:

```
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml_above, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
film =  tree.xpath("//movie/*/text()")
for i in film:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
DVD
1981
PG

            'Archaeologist and adventurer Indiana Jones 
            is hired by the U.S. government to find the Ark of the 
            Covenant before the Nazis.'
```